# How to set ServletContext property for a bean in Spring XML metadata configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I tried searching here on SO but i couldn't find a solution. I have some XML metadata like the following.

```
<bean class="javax.servlet.ServletContext" id="servletContext" />

<bean class="com.abc.ProductController">
    <property name="servletContext" ref="servletContext"/>
</bean>
```

With this configuration I am getting an exception saying that `"javax.servlet.ServletContext"` is an interface and it couldn't create a bean with the id `servletContext`. The ProductController class is in some jar which I can't modify but I want it as a bean in my application. It has ServletContext property autowired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to create a bean for `ServletContext` in a XML config spring application, you could use a `BeanFactory<ServletContext>` implementing `ServletContextAware`

```
public class ServletContextFactory implements FactoryBean<ServletContext>,
            ServletContextAware{
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public ServletContext getObject() throws Exception {
        return servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ServletContext.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

}
```

You can then declare :

```
<bean class="org.app.ServletContextFactory" id="servletContext" />

<bean class="com.abc.ProductController">
    <property name="servletContext" ref="servletContext"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just autowire the context in your controller:

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext context;
```

Comment: Why do you want to inject something then? ;)

Comment: In that case it is not scanned and no DI is taking place. Can you post your xyz-servlet.xml?

Comment: I have mentioned the xml. The jar that I have is obfuscated. So, probably that annotation is mission from that jar.

Comment: With out this configuration other beans and app is working fine

Comment: If the property has `@Autowired` it isn't processed make sure that you have enabled annotation processing. Spring isn't going to automatically scan annotations. Make sure you have `<context:annotation-config />` or a `<context:component-scan />` to enable annotation processing.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for your kind response. I am scanning for beans.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference the servlet context in your XML like this because its lifecycle is controlled by the servlet container.

The solution is to have `com.abc.ProductController` implement [ServletContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletContextAware.html) and then Spring will set it for you.

Comment: So could you create a new class in your webapp which extends `ProductController` (if it isn't final) and implements `ServletContextAware`? You'd then have a handle on the `ServletContext` via the `setServletContext` method and, depending on superclass method visibility could set it that way. A lot of 'ifs' admittedly, but it might work!

Answer (score 0):

With java config use **ServletContextFactory** created by Serge Ballesta above and:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContextFactory servletContextFactory;

    @Bean
    public ServletContextFactory servletContextFactory() {
         return new ServletContextFactory();
    }
}
```