# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet, with Thymeleaf and Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to integrate Spring 4 with Thymeleaf, but I got

```
WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hire-platform/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

And content of `/WEB-INF/templates/index.html` is not displayed. Here is `mvc-dispatcher-servlet-xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
>

<bean
    id="viewResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver"
    p:templateEngine-ref="templateEngine"
    p:characterEncoding="UTF-8"
>
</bean>

<bean
    id="servletContext"
    class="beans.ServletContextFactory"
></bean>

<bean
    id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/templates/"
    p:suffix=".html"
    p:templateMode="HTML5"
>
    <constructor-arg ref="servletContext"/>
</bean>
<bean
    id="templateEngine"
    class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine"
    p:templateResolver-ref="templateResolver"
>
</bean>
```

Where `servletContext` bean is fully copy-pasted from [How to set ServletContext property for a bean in Spring XML metadata configuration answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26633427/3368498), it is needed as constructor parameter as I found in my previous question, [Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver]: No default constructor found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38057341/failed-to-instantiate-org-thymeleaf-templateresolver-servletcontexttemplatereso). I think it should redirect to HTML file (`index.html`), when I used JSP (`index.jsp`) instead of Thymeleaf, it worked. Maybe I am missing something in `applicationContext.xml` file? Here is how `applicationContext.xml` file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
   ">

<jdbc:embedded-database id="DataSource" type="HSQL">
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<context:component-scan base-package="beans"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

I removed `Spring AOP` part, `SessionFactory` bean and `<!--<mvc:annotation-driven/>-->` comment because I think they are not needed here.
I have Thymeleaf dependencies from Maven included in `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

So, I am pretty sure that I am missing something simple, like one configuration line. I would be grateful if anybody will help me, thank you in advance. **P.S.**
 I also include web.xml file, because I see similar questions have it:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- The Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root WebApplicationContext. It is registered to Servlet Container -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I also have tried to add a Controller:

```
@Controller
public final class MainController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String displayFirstView () {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

But it did not help. **Solution**: I missed `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in `applicationContext.xml` and I have to have a controller for first view (like `MainController` which I included here). Thanks for users which helped me a lot with this problem.

Comment: Look in the Server log. mybe a Problem in the deployment

Comment: @Jens I got only `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.LANGUAGES_LIST` related with Hibernate in `Tomcat Catalina` tab, but when I used JSP without Thymeleaf, it also occurred but index.jsp was displayed

Comment: Looks like you have to check your db Access data

Comment: @Jens Problems were that I didn't have `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and didn't have `@Controller` for index file. Weird for me, but it's how it was. I can use DB properly even with this errors, it is development configuration and sooner or later Hsql will be replaces with Postgres. Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` which is required to read the `@Controller` annotation. Try to add it.

Comment: Thanks for help, it is weird for me because in previous project I didn't use Controller for first view (index.jsp), maybe because I had `@RestController`s with AngularJS, I am quite new to templating with JSP/Thymeleaf. Thank you again, now it works like a charm.

Comment: I am happy for that ;) If you used in previous project with AspectJ, i think that was because there is aspectj autoproxy or something like that. I dont know excatly, try to look at Spring docs. But when you need to use annotation @Controller in Spring MVC, you have to add it.

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see from below link, your viewResolver should reference the templateEngine.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html

Comment: I added to viewResolver a templateEngine: `p:templateEngine-ref="templateEngine"` but it still won't work. I also added a `web.xml` content, maybe there something is wrong which I can't find

Comment: Isn't it just a problem of mapping to your servlet ? This should be  `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: @J.Mengelie Thank you for your attention, I added it and still will not work unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a controller to return your view ? You should have one that return you index.html

Comment: I had, but I missed `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` mentioned by @Hrabosh, now it works, thank you so much for help. It is weird, because in previous project I didn't need to use separated `@Controller` for index `file`, maybe because it used `@RestController` and AngularJS. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't noticed in your long post. Nice for you :)